# How to use packages installed via easy_install in zsh?

Tags: python, macos, pip, zsh, easy-install

I use OS X (Mountain Lion) and ZSH. I can use easy_install to install some python packages but if I want to use the command in my ZSH afterwards I just get something like this:

> zsh: command not found: virtualenv

Have I forgotten to include anything to my $PATH or so? Hope you can help me out :)

Comment: Try to echo $PATH before and after running easy_install.

Comment: How did you install it? I ran `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install virtualenv`, which puts it in `/usr/local/bin/`. I think by default that directory should be in your `PATH`; otherwise, edit your `.zshrc` accordingly.

Comment: I just installed it with the easy_install command without the absolut path and sudo.. where are the packages then?

Comment: Perhaps you don't need `sudo`. But have a good look at the output that `virtualenv` is/was giving you: it should say where it put `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint @Evert I had to add `/usr/local/share/python` to my `$PATH` and now everything works fine.

Comment: You could also symlink the executable to `/usr/local/bin`, because this path seems rather awkward to me to contain binaries; with the symlink, you may be less surprised in the future. Of course, if you install more through easy_install, it makes sense to add this to your path if more binaries end up there.